# API's to connect to facebook from windows phone?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a windows phone app that should allows user to post status updates from within the application. Any link for the API's or help documentation that allows us to connect to facebook  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Facebook C# SDK [here](http://csharpsdk.org/)

There is a sample you can look into about how to use the Facebook C# SDK [here on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample) in your Windows Phone App

Answer (score 1):

Here is the starting point of using `Facebook API`

http://developers.facebook.com/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/

[Facebook_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Facebook_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application)